# for loop and symlinking dotfiles

Tags: bash, for-loop, symlink, dotfiles

I am trying to read through dotfile repos in order to learn how to maintain my own dotfiles.
Here is an example that I am looking at:

```
pushd homedir > /dev/null 2>&1

for file in .*; do
  if [[ $file == "." || $file == ".." ]]; then
    continue
  fi

  # make backup
  # ...
  # ...

  # create the new link
  ln -s ~/.dotfiles/homedir/$file ~/$file
  echo -en '\tlinked';ok
done

popd > /dev/null 2>&1
```

1. Why is `.*` used to iterate over the files in homedir.
2. Is the following if-statement necessary account for the fact that .* expands to `.` and `..` and therefore would include files outside of working dir?

Comment: 1. The `.*` glob matches dot files (`.` followed by anything). 2. The `ln` command would fail on  `.` and `..`, since those already exist in every directory.

Comment: aaaahaa! thank you very much.